# How can I redirect a GitHub project to another location?

Tags: 301-redirect, github

How can I redirect a GitHub project to another location? Example:

I have this project:

```
https://github.com/myuser/foo
```

And I manually moved the content from the old repository to a folder inside a new repository. And I did commit on the new one to upload the files.

```
https://github.com/myuser/bar/foo
```

And the old repository only has a `README.md` file with the following content:

```
go to the new link https://github.com/myuser/bar/foo
```

What I want is to remove that `README.md` and instead have a real redirect 301 of:

```
https://github.com/myuser/foo
to
https://github.com/myuser/bar/foo
```

I tried it with an `index.html`, but it didn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://github.com/myuser/bar/foo">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

With an `.htaccess` and it doesn't work either:

```
Redirect 301 / https://github.com/myuser/bar/foo
```

How do I do it (if it can be done)?

PD: I can't use the GitHub Transfer tool, because I do the commits from the console and the local commits would be delayed compared to the online repo.